# Download a file programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a Google Sheets application that generates a file that needs to be uploaded to the HMRC Government Network. They only accept an open document format (`.ods`) in a file originally formatted and generated by HMRC.

The only way I can currently do this is to manually download the data into my PC as an `.ods` file. I had hoped to be able to directly upload to HMRC a file that is in my `Google File Drive Stream` which I had thought would be a real file but it turns out not to be so! HMRC will not look at it.

So has anyone any idea whether `DriveApp` or any other Google Apps Script method can download the file, as you can do manually?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be using [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) in Google Apps Script and use [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) in your script. Using `files.get` method you can access export links from a file and select the one you need.

You will also need to prompt a dialog to click on the link because I believe you cannot directly open an URL from Google Apps Script.

This code could work for you:

```
function exportToODS(fileId){
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  var openOfficeURL = file.exportLinks["application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"];
  showDialog('Click here to export',openOfficeURL);
}

function showDialog(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Export to ODS");
}
```

Remember that you need to [enable Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) before using them:

> To use an advanced Google service, follow these instructions:
>
> 1. In the script editor, select **Resources > Advanced Google services...**.
> 2. In the dialog that appears, click the **on/off** switch next to the service you want to use.
> 3. At the bottom of the dialog, click the link for the **Google API Console**.
> 4. In the console, click into the filter box and type part of the name of the API (for example, "Calendar"), then click the name once
>      you see it.
> 5. On the next screen, click **Enable API**.
> 6. Close the API Console and return to the script editor. Click **OK** in the dialog. The advanced service you enabled is now available in
>      autocomplete.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Ruben - thanks so much. am getting a "missing parameter on this line
function showDialog('mervyn.thomas','https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mh1ijX4nI4Qp0tKpJpsqi3o6DyTXWi9ivknp4rTqSA0/edit#gid=1998119204'') {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mh1ijX4nI4Qp0tKpJpsqi3o6DyTXWi9ivknp4rTqSA0/edit#gid=1998119204+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+mervyn.thomas+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Export to ODS");
}

Comment: You don't need to write that information in showDialog function. Just change fileId with your file ID, in this case: 1mh1ijX4nI4Qp0tKpJpsqi3o6DyTXWi9ivknp4rTqSA0

Comment: Now showing "missing formal parameter" on the ShowDialoge line of code which now is:
function showDialog('1mh1ijX4nI4Qp0tKpJpsqi3o6DyTXWi9ivknp4rTqSA0') {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mh1ijX4nI4Qp0tKpJpsqi3o6DyTXWi9ivknp4rTqSA0/edit#gid=1998119204+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+mervyn.thomas+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Export to ODS");

Comment: Ok, please just copy and paste this code, don't change anything: `function showDialog() {
  var header = 'Click here to export';
  var file = Drive.Files.get("1mh1ijX4nI4Qp0tKpJpsqi3o6DyTXWi9ivknp4rTqSA0");
  var url = file.exportLinks["application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"];
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+header+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Export to ODS");
}`.

Comment: Hi i did that but recieved an error message on line 195 which "said missing; before statement (line195)   Line 195 was the last bit after the last ; which starts
var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+........ and to the final }   
Would it be any use if I shared the source file publically or to your email and you try to run the script yourself?

Comment: Ok, share it to "anyone with the link can edit" and paste the source file link here

Comment: Here is the link to the source sheet.
Thanks for persisting with me on this.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mh1ijX4nI4Qp0tKpJpsqi3o6DyTXWi9ivknp4rTqSA0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for sharing but I need edit permissions to access Apps Script

Comment: sorry about that. Here is the edit permission:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mh1ijX4nI4Qp0tKpJpsqi3o6DyTXWi9ivknp4rTqSA0/edit?usp=sharing